# ¿Por que mi programa se queda pasmado en c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
system("pause") or input loop */
/*Problema 3
```

Se va a colocar una máquina para calcular el costo por el uso de un estacionamiento. Se te pide realices un programa que dada la cantidad 
de horas que se utilizó el estacionamiento y la cantidad de dinero que el cliente dará a la máquina para pagar, 
genere un reporte con el  el monto total y la cantidad de monedas de 10, 5, 2 y 1 que se  debe como cambio.
Para realizar el programa toma en cuenta lo siguiente:

El costo por hora de estacionamiento es de 12 pesos.
La maquina solo contará con monedas de 10, 5, 2 y 1 peso.
La cantidad máxima que puede pagar el cliente es 999 pesos.
El programa debe tratar de dar el menor número de monedas a cambio.
Ejemplo:

Si el cliente usó el estacionamiento por 6 horas y paga con un billete de 100 pesos, el programa debe indicar que se debe pagar $72 pesos
 por lo que hay que regresar $28 pesos: 2 monedas de 10, 1 monedas de 5, 1 moneda de 2 y 1 monedas de 1.

```
*/
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int horas_estacionamiento,total_a_pagar,moneda_5,moneda_10,moneda_2,moneda_1,pago,cambio;
    cout<<"¿Cuantas horas estuvo en el estacionamiento?"<<"\n";
        cin>>horas_estacionamiento;
        total_a_pagar=horas_estacionamiento*12;
    cout<<"El Total A Pagar Es De:" <<total_a_pagar <<"\n"; 
    cout<<"Por Favor Ingrese El Dinero\n";
        cin>>pago;
            while(pago>999){
                cout<<"El Maximo De Dinero Que Puede Ingresar Son 999 Pesos...\n";
                cout<<"El Total A Pagar Es De:" <<total_a_pagar <<"\n"; 
                cout<<"Por Favor Ingrese El Dinero\n";
                    cin>>pago;
            }

            if(total_a_pagar==pago){
                cout<<"Gracias Por Su Estadia En El Estacionamiento :)\n";
            }

                else{

                        cambio=pago-total_a_pagar;
                    while(pago!=total_a_pagar){
                        if(cambio%10){
                            moneda_10++;
                            pago=pago-10;
                            cambio=cambio-10;}
                        else{
                            if(cambio%5){
                                moneda_5++;
                                pago=pago-5;
                                cambio=cambio-5;}
                            else{
                                if(cambio%2){
                                    moneda_2++;
                                    pago=pago-2;
                                    cambio=cambio-2;}
                                else{
                                    moneda_1++;
                                    pago--;
                                    cambio--;
                                }   

                            }
                        }





                    }
                    if(cambio==0){
                        cout<<"Gracias Por Su Estadia En El Estacionamiento :)\n";
                        cout<<"El Cambio Total Es:\n" <<moneda_10<<" Monedas De 10 Pesos\n" <<moneda_5 
                        <<" Monedas De 5 Pesos\n" <<moneda_2 <<" Monedas De 2 Pesos\n" <<moneda_1 <<" Monedas de 1 Pesos\n";
                        cout<<pago;
                        }
                }







    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C++ el operador `%` se usa para calcular el resto de una división, mientras que para obtener el cociente tienes que usar el operador `/`.

```
X / Y = A
X % Y = B
(A * Y) + B = X
```

Que dicho con números:

```
7 / 4 = 1
7 % 4 = 3
(1 * 4) + 3 = 7
```

Esto viene a que estás empleando el operador incorrecto:

```
if(cambio%10){
    moneda_10++;
    pago=pago-10;
    cambio=cambio-10;
}
```

Fíjate los resultados de `cambio%10`:

```
cambio = 0  -> cambio%10 = 0
cambio = 1  -> cambio%10 = 1
cambio = 2  -> cambio%10 = 2
cambio = 3  -> cambio%10 = 3
cambio = 4  -> cambio%10 = 4
cambio = 5  -> cambio%10 = 5
cambio = 6  -> cambio%10 = 6
cambio = 7  -> cambio%10 = 7
cambio = 8  -> cambio%10 = 8
cambio = 9  -> cambio%10 = 9
cambio = 10 -> cambio%10 = 0
cambio = 11 -> cambio%10 = 1
...
```

Es decir, el programa ignorará el bucle cuando `cambio` sea divisor de 10, cuando lo esperable es que la ejecución entrase en el bucle cuando `cambio` **sea mayor o igual** a 10 (mientras `cambio>=10` se podrá pagar con monedas de 10).

Por otro lado, es posible concatenar las secuencias de `if-else`, lo que evita que el código tenga demasiadas indentaciones (lo que dificulta su legibilidad).

Adicionalmente, date cuenta de que es **imprescindible** inicializar las variables. No hacerlo implica que van a partir de un valor aleatorio (básicamente el que tenga previamente la memoria asignada a la variable). No atender a este punto hará que tu programa funcione incorrectamente **SIEMPRE**.

El algoritmo corregido debería quedar más bien así:

```
int moneda_5 = 0, moneda_10 = 0, moneda_2 = 0,moneda_1 = 0
while(pago!=total_a_pagar)
{
  if(cambio>10)
  {
    moneda_10++;
    pago=pago-10;
    cambio=cambio-10;
  }
  else if(cambio>5)
  {
    moneda_5++;
    pago=pago-5;
    cambio=cambio-5;
  }
  else if(cambio>2)
  {
    moneda_2++;
    pago=pago-2;
    cambio=cambio-2;
  }
  else
  {
    moneda_1++;
    pago--;
    cambio--;
  }   
}
```

Aunque si le das una segunda pensada te darás cuenta de que no hace falta un bucle `while` para calcular el cambio. Para ello podemos aprovechar el operador `%` (que cosas...)

```
int moneda_10 = cambio / 10
cambio %= 10
int moneda_5 = cambio / 5
cambio %= 5
int moneda_2 = cambio / 2
int moneda_1 = cambio % 2
```

Es fácil verificarlo con un ejemplo:

```
322 - 120 = 202

moneda_10 = 202 / 10 = 20
cambio = 202 % 10 = 2
moneda_5 = 2 / 5 = 0
cambio = 2 % 5 = 2
moneda_2 = 2 / 2 = 1
moneda_1 = 2 % 2 = 0
```

Así, el cambio serán:

```
20 monedas de 10 = 200
1 moneda de 2    =   2
TOTAL            = 202
```

Answer (score -1):

El bucle es acá:

```
                    while(pago!=total_a_pagar){
                    if(cambio%10){
                        moneda_10++;
                        pago=pago-10;
                        cambio=cambio-10;}
```

También veo dudosa la manera en que usas el '%' creo que iria el '/' que son dos cosas diferentes.

y las variables del cambio debes forzarlas en cero antes de empezar a sumar. porque arrancar con un valor 'basura'.